# sequence problem from placement test

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sequence $a_n$ is defined by $a_0 = 1$ and $a_{n+1} = 2a_{n}+2$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\ldots$

What is the value of $a_3$?  I really am not understanding this.  Can anyone help?  My thinking is $a=4$ so $2*a+2 = 8+2= 10$.  But the correct answer is $22$...

Comment: I suspect the recurrence is supposed to be $a_{n+1}=2a_n+2$.  Is that correct?

Comment: You are correct, I made an error putting that in.

Comment: So I have to calculate the values for the previous numbers in the sequence in order to solve this? I graduated High School in 78 so I am not remembering this as well as I hoped.

Comment: How do you rewrite the correct version of this?

Comment: I showed that in my answer.  Is there anything you don't understand about it?

Comment: I think I see it now.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You can find a closed form solution, but it is more work than just computing three terms.  You certainly have to understand how a recurrence works to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small index you can just compute directly from the recurrence.  You have $$a_1=2a_0+2=2\cdot 1+2=4\\a_2=2\cdot 4+2=10\\a_3=2\cdot 10+2=22$$

To find a closed form we can note that the original $1$ gets doubled $n$ times as part of $a_n$.  The added $2$s give the sum $2^n+2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+\ldots 2$, which is a finite geometric series summing to $2^{n+1}-2$ so our closed from is $$a_n=2^n+2^{n+1}-2$$.  We can prove it is correct by induction.